# The best way to predict performance without actually porting the code?

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu, parallel-port

I believe there are people with the same experience with me,
where he/she must give a (estimated) performance report of
porting a program from sequential to parallel with some
designated multicore hardwares, with a very few amount of
time given.

For instance, if a 10K LoC sequential program was given and
executes on Intel i7-3770k (not vectorized) in 100 ms, how
long would it take to run if one parallelizes the code to a Tesla
C2075 with NVIDIA CUDA, given that all kinds of
parallelizing optimization techniques were done? (but you're
only given 2-4 days to report the performance? assume that
you didn't know the algorithm at all. Or perhaps it'd be
safer if we just assume that it's an impossible situation
to finish the job)

Therefore, I'm wondering, what most likely be the fastest
way to give such performance report? Is it safe to calculate
solely by the hardware's capability, such as GFLOPs peak and
memory bandwidth rate? Is there a mathematical way to
calculate it? If there is, please prove your method with
the corresponding problem description and the algorithm, and
also the target hardwares' specifications.

Or perhaps there already exists such tool to (roughly)
estimate code porting?

(Please don't the answer: 'kill yourself is the fastest way.')

Comment: In order to port a code on GPUs, you need to use adapted parallel algorithms, adapted data structures for memory coalescing etc. The final speedup will depend on that. The thing is, some problems are just not GPU-friendly, or at least not without rethinking the whole implementation. What kind of algorithms are you working on? Can the sequential bottlenecks be transformed into SIMD algorithms?

Comment: I was thinking of more to like general scientific computations and not depend on the accelerator type; whether it's GPU, CPU, or FPGA. I know the question is very unspecific, but, thinking the other way around, might change the parallel computing solution business and take it to a higher level, where R&D costs can be greatly reduced by using this so called multiplatform performance estimator tool.

Comment: As @HighPerformanceMark said, a method like this would certainly be too complex to develop. However, with the increasing work on projects that aim at unifying the different parallelization architectures/libraries (e.g. OpenACC), we can imagine that a tool like this may appear in the future. That would certainly make our life easier! In the meantime, peak performance evaluation, algorithmic considerations and benchmarks of similar problems seem to be our only solution.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I'll bite, here's a rule of thumb I just made up:

First calculate the number of Gflops (G floating-point operations per second) that your current architecture and your target architecture can deliver.  Next compute the number of Gflop (G floating-point operations) that your benchmark code requires and measure how long it takes to execute.  Now calculate the ratio of Gflops that your code consumed to the Gflops your computer delivered, it's probably around 10% for any long-running, numerically-intensive code (the kind that it might be worthwhile porting to a GPU).  Now apply that ratio to the target computer Gflops and see how much faster the program might be on the new architecture.

Next, **and this is the most important step**, throw away all the material you used in making the calculations; under no circumstances must you ever reveal a measurement of a hypothetical speed-up to management, customers, or even your closest relations.  If you to, you **will** have to TWEP them.

I've done a lot of code optimisation-for-performance and am currently managing a team of parallel compute experts improving the performance of a large scientific code.  The only commitment I have ever made to management (etc), and the only one you can ever make, is that at the end of the project the code will not be any slower than at the start -- so always build in to your project plan a day at the end to roll back all the changes made if the new version of the code is actually slower.

There are simply too many variables at play to be able to make supportable predictions about improving the performance of a program by moving it to a different platform; the only reliable guide is to port it and measure.  For scientific codes, where 80% of the run time is consumed by 20% of the code, you might be able to port only that 20% relatively easily and derive useful measurements from that.

As @BenC has already noted porting to a GPU may, to get the best performance, require a complete rewrite of the code and this leads to my final point -- your question ignores the costs of porting.  It's only when you can estimate these that you can start to make informed decisions about whether or not to port.  At some stage, though, you're going to have to convince someone that a 3-month effort (say) to port (part of) a code to a new architecture, with no promise of benefits at the end of the work, is a leap in the dark worth taking.

Comment: How about the memory load/store overhead occuring in the kernel (bottleneck) part? And how would you take atomic (blocking/resource sharing) executions into consideration? Could you elaborate on the calculation part and/or give some examples?

Comment: No I couldn't elaborate or give some examples, and no I wouldn't take account of the issues you raise.  The take-home message from my answer is, or is intended to be, *it is not possible to predict with any precision the performance of a code after it has been ported to a new architecture*.  To be more precise, my belief is that any model which can make such predictions precisely will be no less complex, nor less costly to create, than porting the code in the first place. If I had a tool or technique for generating such predictions I wouldn't be giving them away on SO :-)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark is absolutely correct. Sadly, there's no magical tool to predict the parallel speedup of a black box program. One can compare sequential and parallel algorithms and give a hypothetical peak speedup. This usually gives a good idea of what to expect. However, taking the properties of the parallel architecture into account makes things a lot more complicated. Take CUDA for instance. In many cases, the final advice between 2 different CUDA implementations is: "implement both and measure". Moreover, hardware-related bottlenecks can be of very different nature and importance.

Comment: The worse thing is, I cannot agree more with you guys. Well that was absolutely the main reason I submitted the question, needless to say. It'll definitely be interesting if we can analyze several algorithms and write the mathematical proofs stating that such estimation is merely preposterous. I know it's compilcated, but definitely not impossible.

Comment: Don't feel bad about disagreeing with me; come back when you've developed your predictive model and show me, and the other nay-sayers around who agree with me, that I am wrong.  And, my last contribution on this question, nowhere do I state that it is impossible to predict the performance of a ported code, just that it is equivalent in complexity to porting the code.